# Return a dynamic list of json objects in Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an action in controller which performs a logic to return a list of json objects. In postman, I want to get this list in json format.

```
    [HttpPost("display")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayPersons([FromBody] Person person)
    {
           var generatedFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(await 
                      httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            
            return Ok(generatedFile);
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on the `generatedFile`, I get the values. But on postman, it does not display anything. How can I display the nested list of json objects on postman?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo to pass List to postman,you need to make sure generatedFile is a `list<object>`,and in postman response you need to make sure status is 200 and you are watching body rather than Cookies,Headers or Test Results:
[image]

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost("display")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayPersons([FromBody]List<dynamic> list)
        {
            return Ok(list);
        }
```

Testjson:

```
[
    {
    "Id":1,
    "Name":"sss",
    "Class":"c1"
    },
    {
    "Id":2,
    "Name":"www",
    "Class":"c2"
    }
]
```

result:
[image]